# Making An Element's Height Resizable in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize, draggable

I am making a window in the bottom of my HTML page that I would like to be resizeable when the user clicks and drags. This is what I have so far:

```js
var main = document.getElementById("dragWindow")
var dragTop = document.querySelector("#dragWindow .draggerTop")
var dragTopDown = false

dragTop.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  dragTopDown = true
})

document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  dragTopDown = false
})

document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (dragTopDown == false) {
    return
  }

  var h = (window.innerHeight - e.clientY) + "px"
  main.style.top = "calc(100% - " + h + ")"
})
```

```css
#dragWindow {
  background: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: calc(100% - 150px);
}

#dragWindow .draggerTop {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
  cursor: ns-resize;
}
```

```html
Page content here...

<div id="dragWindow">
  <div class="draggerTop"></div>
</div>
```

In the above example, the dragger doesn't work very well. It is slow and won't move most of the time. Is there something that I am missing? It mainly seems to have trouble moving back upward. Also, when you release the mouse, it still is draggable.

I know that there is the CSS `resize` property, however, I am trying to make a custom version with js.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I figuired it out.
Rather than using `document.body` for the event listeners, I should have used just `document`. Like this:

```js
var main = document.getElementById("dragWindow")
var dragTop = document.querySelector("#dragWindow .draggerTop")
var dragTopDown = false

dragTop.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
  dragTopDown = true
})

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
  dragTopDown = false
})

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
  if (dragTopDown == false) {
    return
  }

  var h = (window.innerHeight - e.clientY) + "px"
  main.style.top = "calc(100% - " + h + ")"
})
```

```css
#dragWindow {
  background: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: calc(100% - 150px);
}

#dragWindow .draggerTop {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: gray;
  cursor: ns-resize;
}
```

```html
Page content here...

<div id="dragWindow">
  <div class="draggerTop"></div>
</div>
```